# Xamarin firebase crash reporting ios with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, firebase-crash-reporting

I've followed the following getting started https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseioscrashreporting
Im currently struggling with uploading symbol files in Visual Studio, I've added the command which uploads the symbols to the Post Build Event but getting **FIND: Parameter format not correct** in the output after building.

note: I also installed http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys which has sh executor.